# How to Request Async by interval using rxjs in Angular 2

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs5

I want to set interval in http request using rxjs. I need to send data on server from n seconds after request finish.

```ts
Observable.interval(10000)
                  .?(() => {
                      //request for server. return Observable
                      return this.getData();
                  })
                  .subscribe(() => {
                      console.log("Request done. After 10 second will be next request");
                  });
```

**UPDATE based on `.expand()` suggested by Mark**

```ts
ngOnInit() {
  this.getData()
    .expand(() => Rx.Observable.timer(10 * 1000)
      .concatMap(() => this.getData())
    )
    .subscribe(data => {
      console.log('received new data', data);
    });
}

private getData() {
  return Observable.timer(5000)
    .do(() => console.log("timer"));
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your usecase is an excellent case for the `.expand` operator which can recursively execute and return new values. See this snippet in which i have added a lot of timestamp + debug logging to clarify what is going on.

```js
function getData() {
  // simulate remote call which can take some time
  return Rx.Observable.of('')
    .timestamp()
    .do(i => console.log(`[debug] Going to fetch data from server @${i.timestamp}`))
    .map(i => 'the new JSON blob of data to use') // this would be your actual http.get call
    .delay(1500)
    .timestamp()
    .do(i => console.log(`[debug] Data retreived from server @${i.timestamp}`));
}

getData()
  .expand(_ => Rx.Observable.of('') // we need something to delay upon
    .timestamp()
    .do(i => console.log(`[debug] Waiting 1sec for next getData ${i.timestamp}`))
    .delay(1000)
    .concatMap(() => getData())
  )
  .take(5)
  .subscribe(val => console.log(`New data received @${val.timestamp} : ${val.value}`))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/5.0.3/Rx.js"></script>
```

so initially you subscribe to the `getData()` and expand its value to recursively `delay` for time before retrieving the next `getData()`. No subjects are involved in this approach and your subscription stays available for receiving the new values.

Comment: I didn't know about the `.expand()` operator.... It looks interesting :), I allways felt quite bad using those kinds of stream auto-feedback (that's why I started my answer like "this is complex")

Comment: in this code I have a memory lick. but I can't understand where is it

Comment: I have updated your code in your question. The memory leak occurred because expand expects the function to return an Observable emitting zero or 1 values. Because of the recursion inside expand you created a memory leak - with interval you created a new interval on each interval.

Answer (score 3):

i think you want to request server for something every few seconds. can you try this way

make sure you have imported import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Rx' if you don't import it we get observable not found error sometimes

working plnkr  http://plnkr.co/edit/vMvnQW?p=preview

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {Http} from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/Rx';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Rx';

@Component({
    selector: 'app',
    template: `
      <b>Angular 2 HTTP request every 5 sec RxJs Observables!</b>
      <ul>
        <li *ngFor="let doctor of doctors">{{doctor.name}}</li>
      </ul>

      `
})

export class MyApp {
  private doctors = [];

  constructor(http: Http) {
    Observable.interval(5000)
    .switchMap(() => http.get('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/')).map((data) => data.json())
        .subscribe((data) => {
          this.doctors=data; 
           console.log(data);// see console you get output every 5 sec
        });
  }
}
```

see google inspect console you will be getting new data every 5 sec

Comment: Will request canceled if component will be destroyed?

Comment: its depend on where you are calling it from a service or component. once that calling component is destroyed it should cancel request itself. otherwise you can unsubscribe it in ngOnDestroy() lifecycle hook.

Answer (score 1):

I've read the comments you put in that deleted answer. You want to send a request, then 10 seconds after receiving a response send another request.

That's quite complex, but doable... I think something like this should work:

```
let responseSubject = new Rx.BehaviourSubject({});
responseSubject
    .delay(10000)
    .flatMap(() => {
        return http.get(...)
    })
    .subscribe((res) => {
        responseSubject.onNext({});
        // Your stuff here
    });
```

Here I'm setting up a behaviour so I can feedback when we get a response. Then setup a stream that after 10 seconds of a request, it makes the request and yields the response.

Edit: I'm missing something... the first request will take 10 seconds before it starts. Then I would rewrite as:

```
let responseSubject = new Rx.ReplaySubject(1);
responseSubject
    .delay(10000)
    .startWith({})
    .flatMap(() => {
        return http.get(...)
    })
    .subscribe((res) => {
        responseSubject.onNext({});
        // Your stuff here
    });
```

Comment: Isn't it a trivial task? Send request on server by timer... My problem is that request can be long...

Comment: No, because it's not every 10 seconds you want to send the request, but 10 seconds after you get each response, right? Else if each request takes 30 seconds, you would have 3 requests going on at the same time

Comment: These kinds of feedback make things complex... You send a request, but this depends on the response made by a previous request

Comment: it seems that ReplaySubject has no method onNext

Comment: @Illorian it does, by definition https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/subjects/replaysubject.md Check your Rx implementation it's equivalent... maybe you are using another version?

Comment: maybe problem in d.ts file. but next will help me. thanks a lot =)

Comment: Using a subject to procedurally invoke the `next()` method so you can start the next iteration is asking for trouble. It requires you to create a side-effect either in the `.do()` or `.subscribe()` and you there are other solutions which are better for this case (see my answer below using `.expand()`)